# sublime-3 apigen destination not set error

Tags: settings, sublimetext3, apigen

i've just installed apigen package on sublime 3. 
When i run apigen->generate,
console says: "Destination is not set. Use '-d' or config to set it"

here is my apigen.neon file

```
source: 
    /mysourcefolder
destination: 
    /somedestionationfolder
```

and Apigen.sublime-settings

```
{
    "phpBin":"/usr/bin/php",
    "pharPath": "/usr/local/bin/apigen",
    "configFileName" : "/var/www/tapt.im/protected/modules/web/apigen.neon",
    "additionalGenerateArgs": []
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the ApiGen [repo](https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen), under the [Usage](https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen#usage) section in the README, it appears that `apigen.neon` files are based on [YAML](http://yaml.org). As such, your file is invalid. It should be either of the form

```
setting: value
```

or

```
setting:
  - value
```

To make things easy, just put each of your settings on a single line:

```
source: /path/to/source
destination: /path/to/dest
```